# What is the difference between sqq and ff?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations, latin

What's the difference between sqq. and ff.?

[*The Apocryphal Acts of Paul, Peter, John, Andrew and Thomas*](https://archive.org/stream/apocryphalactso00pick#page/8/mode/2up) by Bernhard Pick has, for example, these 4 references in a row:

> Hennecke, N eutestamentliche Apokryphen, 1904, 358 **ff.**
>   Handbuch, 1904, 359 **sqq.**
>   Schmidt, Acta Pauli, 1904, 145-161.
>   Bardenhewer, Patrology, p. 102 **ff.**

Why the variation?

Comment: Hmm, *ff* means "the following pages" (in German, IIRC), and "sqq" means "and what follows" (ditto Latin). Maybe Pick, here, is using *ff* to mean "and the *next few* pages", and *sqq* to mean "and *everything* that follows"? Or maybe the manuscripts have a different format?

Comment: I've no idea why your source used both. It's worth noting that the Wikipedia page of [List of Latin abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_abbreviations) has **f/ff = folio/foliis** = "and following" *This abbreviation is used in citations to indicate an unspecified number of pages following the specified page.* They don't include ***sqq*** at all, but [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sqq.) has **sqq** *abbreviation for
"the following ones" [from Latin **sequentia**]*. They imply it's a specifically ***legal*** usage.

Comment: Bear in mind that  typesetting a book at the time was an intensive process, no ctrl+h to replace something, My guess is that the author used ff in a first edition and then sqq in a second revised one  and did not bother replacing what had already been done.

Comment: @P.Obertelli It may not be so simple as that. See [this crazy footnote](http://books.google.com/books?id=NUn-AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=ff+sqq&source=bl&ots=GsPhHr8skQ&sig=tdzSStxvDV7ZisyLDrYHm2K8nFw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV_fv9p4DOAhVEcD4KHRoyBQMQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=ff%20sqq&f=false), for example. And even [Cambridge Modern History](http://books.google.com/books?id=p_HgAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA845&lpg=PA845&dq=bibliography+ff+sqq&source=bl&ots=cyuUIahExQ&sig=JVtdpFlc-kBqhM_zFith3ZO9vrE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis0LXLqIDOAhVBPz4KHSjuBskQ6AEIRjAH#v=onepage&q=bibliography%20ff%20sqq&f=false) uses both.

Comment: ok, this picks my interest.

Comment: @P.Obertelli First, I can't help it, *piques*. Sorrysorrysorry. Second, I am becoming more and more convinced that the difference reflects a difference in the format of the work cited. According to [this question and its answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115784/is-the-latin-abbreviation-f-folio-commonly-used-in-page-ranges), for example, a "folio" wasn't originally just "a book", it was "a short work of writing which would take about an hour to make a copy of". So "following folios" doesn't *precisely* mean "following pages".

Comment: Ok, a little Google research turns up that *most* contemporary writers consider the abbreviations synonymous, as well as obsolete. But given the wealth of works I've been able to turn up which use both, consciously, I think there was originally a difference. First, as FF says, often *sqq* (or "et seq") is used in legal contexts. But I think that's a consequence of the distinction between a "folio" and a "page". I think the major difference is that "et seq" (sqq) is means "the following [abstract] *sections*", where "ff." means more literally "the following [well-defined] *folios*".

Comment: @DanBron Folio at the time  also meant a book of big format= > 30 cm

Comment: @DanBron I may have a hint at a solution, by browsing through a few 19th century books I noticed that you can find the combination sq/sqq (singular/plural) or, as in your example, a combination ff-sqq, but I could not find a combination of ff/sq/sqq. According to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff FF can alos be used for ONE page only, whereas sqq is always plural. So I guess, when used in opposition to sqq, ff mean just the one following page for some authors. A way to check it  would be to check the references in the source and see if effectively they refer to only one page or not

Comment: In practical terms, I'd say the difference is mainly that _f(f)._ is in very common use in scholarly writing, while _sqq._ is rare to the point of obscurity. As an editor at a publishing house that publishes scholarly works exclusively, I have never seen _sq(q)._ used, whereas there is almost certain to be at least one _f(f)._ in every one of our books.

Answer (score 4):

The variation appears to be accidental. Pick cites the same 1904 work by Hennecke elsewhere and uses ff, not sqq, in those citations:

> Hennecke, *Neutestamentliche Apokryphen*, 1904, pp. 357 ff. and *Handbuch*, pp. 358 ff. (Pick, [p. 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=yRRhTxUMFIsC&dq=The%20Apocryphal%20Acts%20of%20Paul%2C%20Peter%2C%20John%2C%20Andrew%2C%20and%20Thomas%20By%20Bernhard%20Pick&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false).)
>
> "Petrusakten" in Hennecke, *Neutestamentliche Apokryphen*, 1904 383 ff.; in *Handbuch zu den neutestamentlichen Apokryphen*, 1904, 395 ff. (Ibid., [p. 50](https://books.google.com/books?id=yRRhTxUMFIsC&dq=The%20Apocryphal%20Acts%20of%20Paul%2C%20Peter%2C%20John%2C%20Andrew%2C%20and%20Thomas%20By%20Bernhard%20Pick&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false).)
>
> Schimmelpfeng-Hennecke in Hennecke, *Neutestamentaliche Apokryphen,* 1904, 459 ff.; Handbuch, 1904, 544 ff. (Ibid., [p. 200](https://books.google.com/books?id=yRRhTxUMFIsC&dq=The%20Apocryphal%20Acts%20of%20Paul%2C%20Peter%2C%20John%2C%20Andrew%2C%20and%20Thomas%20By%20Bernhard%20Pick&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q&f=false).)
>
> Raabe-Preuschen in Hennecke, *Neutest. Apokryphen,* 1904, 473 ff., and in Handbuch (1904) 563 ff. (Ibid., [p. 222](https://books.google.com/books?id=yRRhTxUMFIsC&dq=The%20Apocryphal%20Acts%20of%20Paul%2C%20Peter%2C%20John%2C%20Andrew%2C%20and%20Thomas%20By%20Bernhard%20Pick&pg=PA223#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

Further, on [page 359](https://books.google.com/books?id=07Qx223WGMcC&vq=ueber%20die%20acta%20pauli&pg=PA359#v=onepage&q&f=false) of his 1904 *Handbuch,* Hennecke discusses the acts of Paul and Thecla, which is the same topic for which Pick has cited 359 sqq of that work. (Pick, [pp. 8, 9](https://books.google.com/books?id=yRRhTxUMFIsC&dq=The%20Apocryphal%20Acts%20of%20Paul%2C%20Peter%2C%20John%2C%20Andrew%2C%20and%20Thomas%20By%20Bernhard%20Pick&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false).) The first full paragraph of that page begins, *Ueber die Acta Pauli et Theclae, ...* ("About the Acts of Paul and Thecla, ...")