# Abbreviations in Archive Reference

Tags: abbreviations, reference

I've just finished a book about American history, and I somehow turned to the pages of Notes. The words in the archive reference are new to me, I managed to figure out some abbreviation with Google, but there still remains some I can't understand.

The following link is a perfect example with three strange points to me:"fol.","16v", and "17r". You may click it to get a whole picture.

http://www.bbk.ac.uk/boyle/papers/volume-36/volume-36-**fol.16v-17r**

Comment: You haven’t said which ones you don’t understand.

Comment: Very closely related (and with the answer): [Is the Latin abbreviation f {folio} commonly used in page ranges?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115784/is-the-latin-abbreviation-f-folio-commonly-used-in-page-ranges/115803#115803). v = verso and r = recto also addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your link goes to a general page without any of the abbreviations.

**Fol = folio**  OED

> **A. n. With reference to pagination.: 1. A leaf of paper, parchment, etc. (either loose as one of a series, or in a bound volume) which is numbered only on the front.In the early instances the word may have been regarded as Latin. *The front and back of the leaf were referred to as (folio) recto and verso; these words became English as nouns***
>
> 1533   T. More Debellacyon Salem & Bizance i. xiiii. f. lxxxiv   The .xlv. chapyter of myne apologye begynnyng, fo. 243.
>
> 1669   S. Sturmy Mariners Mag. ii. xvii. (margin)    *Place this between folio 202. and folio 203.*

Note the italicised bold above **16v** = 16 verso. **17r** = 17 recto.